# Querying General Date field in Access from Excel (Error 13)

Tags: excel, ms-access-2010, vba

I need to query a general date field in Access Table from Excel.  Please suggest how to format the date correctly for the query to work.  It is probably a minor detail that I’m missing in the query that I can’t figure it out. I've tried to format the date differently and the query worked if the format of date field in Access was changed to **short date** but not with general date format that I need to use.  Here is what worked to query short date in Access:

`SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[MDL_Table1].[UploadDate] BETWEEN " &` `Format(UserForm1.txtStartDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " AND " _`
 `& Format(UserForm1.txtEndDate, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") & " AND "`

I'm including a part of my code.  I've used this code to perform other queries and it worked fine. Also, getDate method does return the date. Please see my code below:

```vb
Dim qc1 As String
Dim DateMin As String
Dim DateMax As String
'add error handling

On Error GoTo errHandler:

'Disable screen flickering.
'FastWB True, 3
DateMin = Format(frmCalendar.getDate(DateMin), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
DateMax = Format(frmCalendar.getDate(DateMax), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
Sheet1.Range("A2:AK5000").ClearContents
dbPath = "H:\DEMO\MDL_IonTorrent.accdb"

'set the search variable
qc1 = "_QC"

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection ' Initialise the collection class variable
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath

SQLwhere = "WHERE "

SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[MDL_Table1].[UploadDate] BETWEEN #" & DateMin & "#     AND #" _
& DateMax & "# AND "

SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[MDL_Table1].[AAchange] LIKE '" & "%" & qc1 & "%" & "' AND "
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [MDL_Table1] "

'Remove the last AND applicable
If SQLwhere = "WHERE " Then
    SQLwhere = ""
Else
    SQLwhere = Left(SQLwhere, Len(SQLwhere) - 5)
End If

strSQL = strSQL & SQLwhere
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset
rs.Open strSQL, cnn
```

Comment: Is this the partial code. You have not dimensioned all the variables. For example `Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection` . You need to dimension all the variables. In excel VBA Format Function has the syntax `Format( expression[,format [,firstdayofweek [,firstweekofyear]]])`. I am not sure it supports getdate method. I understand that you are using form calendar to pick date as your code shows `frmCalendar`. If getdate is not supported then one can write picked dates to worksheet hidden cells and can extract dates from there. Error 13 is caused by Type mismatch ,non declared variables or data mismatch.

Comment: BTW which version of Access and Excel are you using?

Comment: Sorry your tags states ms-access-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
DateMin = Format(frmCalendar.getDate(DateMin), "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

to

```
DateMin = Format(frmCalendar.getDate(DateMin), "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
```

Do the same with datemax.

Comment: @asdev...I'm getting "Can't find a project or a library error. `DateMin = Format(frmCalendar.getDate(DateMin), "mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss")` and `Format` is highlighted.  I wasn't getting this error before on my work computer but I'm now trying to run the code at home.

Comment: Hm... it seems that you are missing a reference.
See this SO-Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507191/cant-find-project-or-library-for-standard-vba-functions according to your problem. Please keep me updated, if it works at your home computer.