# Excel: Can't find project or library

Tags: vba, excel

I have a public function that is referencing `objFileDialog`, which worked fine on one user's PC. However, when moving the project to another PC, I get the error in the title.

It seems that a library may not be enabled on the other user's computer, but I'm not sure what library objFileDialog is housed in.

I would refer to the previous user's PC to match up libraries, but it's already been wiped and reimaged.

[image]

Comment: Does the other user's computer have a different version of Access? Tools->References will show the missing ones.  `FileDialog` is in the Microsoft Office x.x Object Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/824272

You need to reference:Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library

To do this select Tools> References and check the bok with the reference above

Comment: The *version* of the Object Library depends on what is installed on the target machine.

Comment: Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library is referenced on the machine and we still get that error.

Comment: have a look here, could be another library? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507191/cant-find-project-or-library-for-standard-vba-functions

Comment: @Dr.Trey Verify Tools -> References; if any says `(missing)`, that's what you need to fix.

Comment: Are you using Office 15 (2013)? If not you might need to unselect vers15 and select the correct version of Microsoft Office XX.0 Object Library in the references.