# What is the missing library?

Tags: ms-access, vba

On Access VBA, I get an error on `Environ` in this string:

```
path = Environ("Temp") & "\DOTS\"
```

The error I get is the following:

[image]

How can I know what is the missing library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Can't find Project or Library" for standard VBA functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507191/cant-find-project-or-library-for-standard-vba-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Basic Editor, select Tools --> References.

See if there are references whose check box is ticked (they are listed at the top) that start with MISSING: . If so, look further down the list for the version compatible with your application (e.g. if is says MISSING:  Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library look for a lower # in your references list like  Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library)