# VBA - simple macro to move data from created report causes crash or "Can't find project or library"

Tags: excel, vba

I have created very simple macro which is producing report with daily stats (each team has data in separate tab). This macro is connected with macro which is moving data to Master file - it seems like sometimes macro is crashing Master file (unable to open it after macro is done) or file opens but box with "Can't find project or library" appears.

Do you have any idea why this is happening? Could this be caused by proctect, unprocted part? To add - Master file is stored on shared drive.

Macro:

```
    Sub MOVEDATA()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim team As String
Dim cl As Range
Dim xFound As Boolean
Dim MASTERFILE1 As Workbook
Dim MASTERFILE2 As Workbook


Set MASTERFILE1 = Workbooks.Open("G:\something\something\MASTERFILE1.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ("passwordtoprotect")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Visible = True
ws.Unprotect ("passwordtoprotect")
Next ws

'******************NEW DELAYS VER***************'

For Each ws In MASTERFILE1.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
        ws.Activate
        Else
        ws.Activate
        team = ActiveSheet.Name
                With ActiveSheet.Cells
                Set cl = .Find(reportdateopt, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues) ‘reportdateopt is taken from first macro’
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                cl.Select

                        Workbooks(pendingoptname).Activate



                        If team = "" Then Exit Sub
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(team).Select
                        xFound = (Err = 0)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If xFound Then

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    ActiveSheet.Range("F2:B2").Copy
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Activate
                                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Select
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(24, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


                        End If

                        End If
                End With
        End If
Next ws

'******************NOT UP TO DATE VER***************'

For Each ws In MASTERFILE1.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
        ws.Activate
        Else
        ws.Activate
        team = ActiveSheet.Name
                With ActiveSheet.Cells
                Set cl = .Find(reportdateopt, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                cl.Select

                        Workbooks(pendingoptname).Activate


                        team = team
                        If team = "" Then Exit Sub
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(team).Select
                        xFound = (Err = 0)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If xFound Then

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    ActiveSheet.Range("F3:B3").Copy
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Activate
                                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Select
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(31, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


                        End If

                        End If
                End With
        End If
Next ws

'******************OVERDUE VER***************'

For Each ws In MASTERFILE1.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
        ws.Activate
        Else
        ws.Activate
        team = ActiveSheet.Name
                With ActiveSheet.Cells
                Set cl = .Find(reportdateopt, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                cl.Select

                        Workbooks(pendingoptname).Activate


                        team = team
                        If team = "" Then Exit Sub
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(team).Select
                        xFound = (Err = 0)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If xFound Then

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    ActiveSheet.Range("F4:B4").Copy
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Activate
                                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Select
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(38, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


                        End If

                        End If
                End With
        End If
Next ws

'*********************WIP VER*******************'

For Each ws In MASTERFILE1.Worksheets
             If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then

        ws.Activate
        Else
        ws.Activate
        team = ActiveSheet.Name
                With ActiveSheet.Cells
                Set cl = .Find(reportdateopt, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                cl.Select

                        Workbooks(pendingoptname).Activate


                        team = team
                        If team = "" Then Exit Sub
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(team).Select
                        xFound = (Err = 0)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If xFound Then

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Copy
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Activate
                                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Select
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


                        End If

                        End If
                End With
        End If
Next ws

Workbooks(“MASTERFILE1”).Activate

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
    ws.Activate
Else
    ws.Visible = False
End If
Next ws

ActiveWorkbook.Protect ("passwordtoprotect")

MASTERFILE1.Close SaveChanges:=True

Set MASTERFILE2 = Workbooks.Open("G:\something\something\MASTERFILE2.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False)

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:20"))

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ("passwordtoprotect")

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Visible = True
ws.Unprotect ("passwordtoprotect")
Next ws

'******************************WIP DELAYS PR***************'

For Each ws In MASTERFILE2.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
        ws.Activate
        Else
        ws.Activate
        team = ActiveSheet.Name
                With ActiveSheet.Cells
                Set cl = .Find(reportdateopt, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                cl.Select

                        Workbooks(pendingoptname).Activate


                        team = team
                        If team = "" Then Exit Sub
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(team).Select
                        xFound = (Err = 0)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If xFound Then

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    ActiveSheet.Range("F2:B2").Copy
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE2”).Activate
                                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE2”).Select
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(19, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True


                        End If

                        End If
                End With
        End If
Next ws


'******************OVERDUE PR***************'

For Each ws In MASTERFILE2.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
        ws.Activate
        Else
        ws.Activate
        team = ActiveSheet.Name
                With ActiveSheet.Cells
                Set cl = .Find(reportdateopt, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                cl.Select

                        Workbooks(pendingoptname).Activate


                        team = team
                        If team = "" Then Exit Sub
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(team).Select
                        xFound = (Err = 0)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If xFound Then

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    ActiveSheet.Range("F3:B3").Copy
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE2”).Activate
                                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE2”).Select
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(33, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                        End If

                        End If
                End With
        End If
Next ws

'******************WIP PR***************'

For Each ws In MASTERFILE2.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
        ws.Activate
        Else
        ws.Activate
        team = ActiveSheet.Name
                With ActiveSheet.Cells
                Set cl = .Find(reportdateopt, After:=.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not cl Is Nothing Then
                cl.Select

                        Workbooks(pendingoptname).Activate


                        team = team
                        If team = "" Then Exit Sub
                        On Error Resume Next
                        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(team).Select
                        xFound = (Err = 0)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If xFound Then

                                    On Error Resume Next
                                    ActiveSheet.Range("A7").Copy
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE2”).Activate
                                    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
                                    Workbooks(“MASTERFILE2”).Select
                                    ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                        End If

                        End If
                End With
        End If
Next ws

Workbooks(“MASTERFILE2”).Activate

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.Name = "DATA" Or ws.Name = "DATA2" Then
    ws.Activate
Else
    ws.Visible = False
End If
Next ws

ActiveWorkbook.Protect ("passwordtoprotect")

MASTERFILE2.Close SaveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think it is consider `simple` macro, quite a terrible structure, try break it down to different `sub` for better maintenance.

Comment: Hi Kin,

Thanks for reply. I have this in plan but apart from that anything rings bell in regards to errors I am getting?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507191/cant-find-project-or-library-for-standard-vba-functions