# MISSING: NucleusNativeMessagingLib problem

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an error "Compiler Error Can't Find Project or Library" while executing below code:

```
Dim t As String
Dim p As Integer

p = 1

t = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(p).Range.Start, End:=ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(p).Range.End)
t = Replace(Replace(t, Chr(10), ""), Chr(13), "")
```

The problem did not exist an hour ago and shows in the last line and I guess it concerns "Chr", but same happens with unspecified variables. Before it occured I added custom Ribbon XML as per Microsoft turorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file I've done this before and never experienced such a problem) I checked the references and found that one is described as below:

> MISSING: NucleusNativeMessagingLib

I tried on other files, reinstaled Microsoft 365 and nothing helps, do you have any idea how can I solve the issue?

Comment: [Perhaps related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507191/cant-find-project-or-library-for-standard-vba-functions). Do you need the reference? If not, uncheck.

Comment: I honestly don't know :) but as it is not necessary for the VBA itselft- i unchecked it and it helped, but I am more concern what happened there...